# PDO execute() then fetchall() with bound paramaters. I can't get it to work

Tags: pdo

I am new to PDO, and trying this

```
function ExecuteSqlQuery($connection, $sqlQuery, $paramsArray)
{
    try
    {
         $sql = $connection->prepare($sqlQuery);
         $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $sql->execute($paramsArray);
         $result = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    ... etc
```

`$result` always is an empty array.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

`$connection` is valid (I check (not shown), but would throw an exception if not)

```
paramsArray = array('modem_id' => '1');
$sqlQuery = "SELECT vehicle_id FROM vehicles WHERE modem_id=":modem_id"
```

---

[Update]
As requested, here is the code in more detail.

```
function ExecuteSqlQuery($connection, $sqlQuery, $paramsArray)
{
    try
    {
         $sql = $connection->prepare($sqlQuery);
         $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $sql->execute($paramsArray);
         $result = $sql->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

... etc Nothing matters after this point in the function, 
as things have already gone wrong - $result is NULL

    catch (Exception $e)
    {
         echo $e->getMessage();  // This code is not reached
    }
}   // ExecuteSqlQuery()


  $connection = ConnectToDatabase();  // Do you need the code for that? It works, my IDE shows a PDO object
  $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $queryParams = array('modem_id' => "1");
  $sqlQuery = 'SELECT vehicle_id FROM ' . DATABASE_NAME . '.vehicles WHERE modem_id=":modem_id"';
  $result     = ExecuteSqlQuery($connection, $sqlQuery, $queryParams);
```

Comment: You need to learn how to ask a question properly. Instead of posting some bits and pieces of random operators, you have to post **exact** code you tried. To make your code at least *appear* to be working.

Comment: +1 however, there *is* enough there. I show a function, the first few lines of, but not the rest as error has occurred by that point and the values of it's input parameters. What's not to like? I think that more code will only complicate it, but will post more anyway.  Obviously I cannot post the whole app, but if I still don't post enough, please let me know what more I can do in order to help you to be able to help me. Thanks.

Comment: what tutorial you are learning PDO from?

Comment: +1 The tutorial of Google. A fairly mixed bag. I can't find a concrete example of binding an array as the parameter of `execute()` for a SELECT statement, which would fit in with my code structure. Everyone is using multiple `bindparam()` or `execute(array(':key' => $value, 'key2' => $val2, etc)`, both of which look messy for more than a few parameters.

Comment: wut? What you cannot find? an example of how use a variable as a function parameter? Did I get you right and this is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't quote the parameter like you did:

```
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT vehicle_id 
             FROM ' . DATABASE_NAME . '.vehicles 
             WHERE modem_id=":modem_id"';//remove quotes
```

Change it to the following:

```
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT vehicle_id 
             FROM ' . DATABASE_NAME . '.vehicles 
             WHERE modem_id=:modem_id';
```

Comment: +1 the answer, and a loud "D'oh!".  It's always the little things that trip us up. Thanks a thousand thousand, @Meda

Comment: It makes me wonder what made you edit this answer from proper syntax to improper one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I misread it at first, then I fixed it as you can see  ;)

Comment: @YourCommonSense bro where is the syntax error? your comments are always useless